# Installing create-react-app through mobile hotspot

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I am on a Windows 10 pro laptop trying to run `npm install -g create-react-app` from PowerShell ISE and I get the following error:

> ********************************************************************** npm : npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND At line:1 char:2
>   +  npm install -g create-react-app
>   +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError   errno  ENOTFOUND
>
> request to http://registry.npnjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason:
>   getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND   registry.npnjs.org registry.npnjs.org:80
>
> This is a problem related to network connectivity.
>
> In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
>
> If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>
> 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>
> A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> ```
>  C:\Users\FSmith\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-26T19_04_18_254Z-debug.log
> ```
>
> ---

I use a mobile phone for my internet connection (hotspot).  How do i config npm to see my phone as a proxy server so I can install (and run) apps.  I am new to react so please be specific with any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
npm config get proxy
```

If it returns anything, you can clear the configuration by running:

```
npm config delete proxy
```

After that, try running your NPM install again.

If it still doesn't work, you can view all of your NPM config with the following command, it should help further troubleshoot your problems.

```
npm config list ls -l
```